# Browsers show positioned divs differently

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, position

I'm building a test page with a menu bar, but the deviders (basically divs with a width of 1) position themselves differently in Chrome and Mozilla. I'm building it in Chrome, and find it weird that it is doing the positioning thing differently. Does anyone know what might be causing this? My code is as follows:

**HTML**

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="global.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>


<!-------------------------------------------MENUDEV1------------------------------------------->
<div id="menuContainer">
    <!-----------------------------------DEVIDER----------------------------------->
    <div id="menuLogo">
        <a href="/home.html">
            <img id="menuLogo2" src="http://www.placehold.it/126x50/ff0000/000000&text=Logo+gaat+hier">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="menuDevide1"></div>
    <!-----------------------------------DEVIDER----------------------------------->
    <div id="menuPortfolio1">
        <a id="menuPortfolio2" class="menuClick" href="portfolio.html">portfolio</a>

    </div>
    <div id="menuDevide2"></div>
    <!-----------------------------------DEVIDER----------------------------------->
    <div id="menuServices1">
        <a id="menuServices2" class="menuClick" href="services.html">services</a>

    </div>
    <div id="menuDevide3"></div>
    <!-----------------------------------DEVIDER----------------------------------->
    <div id="menuProcess1">
            <a id="menuProcess2" class="menuClick" href="process.html">our process</a>

    </div>
    <div id="menuDevide4"></div>
    <!-----------------------------------DEVIDER----------------------------------->
    <div id="menuContact1">
        <a id="menuContact2" class="menuClick" href="contact.html">contact</a>

    </div>
    <!-----------------------------------DEVIDER----------------------------------->
    </div>
<div id="menuBottomline"></div>
<!-----------Everything from MENUDEV1 up to this point should be considered as a whole.----------->
```

**CSS**

```
#menuContainer{
width:650px;
height:50px;

margin-top:0;
margin-right:auto;
margin-bottom:0;
margin-left:auto;
background-color:rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.46);
}

#menuLogo2{
height:50px;
width:126px;
}
/*ALL "menuDevide" IDS ARE TO BE NUDGED TO THE LEFT 2 TO 3 PIXELS AFTER THE MENU ITEMS HAVE BEEN PLACED!*/
#menuDevide1{
width:1px;
height:45px;

background-color:black;

position:relative;
top:-47.5px;
left:131px;

margin-top:auto;
margin-right:0;
margin-bottom:auto;
margin-left:0;
}

#menuDevide2{
width:1px;
height:45px;

background-color:black;

position:relative;
top:-119.5px;
left:259px;

margin-top:auto;
margin-right:0;
margin-bottom:auto;
margin-left:0;
}

#menuDevide3{
width:1px;
height:45px;

background-color:black;

position:relative;
top:-191.5px;
left:386px;

margin-top:auto;
margin-right:0;
margin-bottom:auto;
margin-left:0;
}

#menuDevide4{
width:1px;
height:45px;

background-color:black;

position:relative;
top:-263.5px;
left:515px;

margin-top:auto;
margin-right:0;
margin-bottom:auto;
margin-left:0;
}

#menuBottomline{
width:100%;
height:1px;
background-color:black;

position:absolute;
top:70px;
left:0px

}


.menuClick{
color:#000000;
text-decoration:none;
font-family: "Open Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
font-size:20px;;
}


.menuClick:hover{
color:#999999;
}


#menuPortfolio1{
position:initial;
top:-83px;
left:13px;
width:126;
}


#menuServices1{
position:initial;
top:-83px;
left:131px;
width:126;
}

#menuProcess1{
position:initial;
top:-83px;
left:131px;
width:126;
}

#menuContact1{
position:initial;
top:-83px;
left:131px;
width:126;
}




#menuPortfolio2{

}


#menuServices2{

}

#menuProcess2{

}

#menuContact2{

}
```

Alternatively, you could check out this [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Whitevan_Candyman/t8W5X/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every browser has its own default settings for font size, margins and/or padding around certain elements, etc. Webdesigners should aim to have their sites display well on all kinds of browsers, but these different default settings can easily lead to problems.

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ is a tool to reset all default css properties to zero in each browser. I tried to add it in your JSfiddle and the style was applying in the same way in FF and Chrome. OFC, now you have to rework it until the wanted result.